# Conversion to Binary - long long and NSUInteger

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, binary

We need to convert the below datatypes to binary:

1. Long long to Binary
2. NSUInteger to Binary

Any help on this would be highly appreciated.

The code i have is :

As per the above link, we have

```
 - (NSString *) longlongToBinary:(long long) val {

long long num = val;
NSString *res = [NSString string];

for (long long i=63; i>=0; i--)
{

    long long div = 1l<<i;
    if ((num&div)==div) res = [res stringByAppendingString:@"1"];
    else res = [res stringByAppendingString:@"0"];
}

return res;
```

}

If the val is 20, then the output i am getting is:

> 0000000000000000000000000001010000000000000000000000000000010100

and this is wrong when i see it in the online convertors.

Comment: You're only using `long`, not `long long`...

Comment: Shouldn't `1l` be `1ll`?

Comment: Just a note, you're not _converting_, you're _formatting_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`long` is only 32 bits. Since the method is named `longlongToBinary`, change all of the `long` variables to `long long`. That will give you the 64 bits you are using.

Now that you have changed most variables to `long long`, change the loop variable `i` back to an `int` and change the `1l` constant to `1ll`.

Comment: I have just changed it but the issue is still the same.

Answer (score 2):

The literal `1l` is still only long. That's why you see the output twice. Change the literal to `1ll`